# Bitbucket git lfs fail to push and pull

Tags: bitbucket, git-push, git-pull, git-lfs

On `git lfs pull`, I get:

```
Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server
```

On `git lfs push origin --all`, I get:

```
(missing) src/some_file_name (c466bb10506eb1404a0746d50069eaacb96abe736bb3351a81a29e1dea5d47c2)
```

How do I recover from this?